# regex запрос для замены текста

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Имеется строка вида : `123/good_126212/55828.jpg`.

Необходимо вставить `/orig/` на вместо `/` между `good_126212/55828.jpg.` и получить строку : `123/good_126212/orig/55828.jpg`.

Использую `[0-9]/`,но он удаляет так же 1 цифру. Как оставить цифру?

Comment: получил нужный результат через формулу в гугл шитс. Теперь вопрос как применить эту формулу к одной ячейке несколько раз?
=СЦЕПИТЬ(REGEXEXTRACT(N9;".*[0-9]/");"orig";REGEXEXTRACT(N9;"/[0-9].*"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам следует использовать группы и выжарения вставки в непассивную группу :

```
(...)  -  Группа.
$n - выражение вставки n-ую непассивную группу.
```

Пример на JavaScript:

```
'123/good_126212/55828.jpg'.replace(new RegExp('(.+/.+)/'), '$1/orig/')
 // "123/good_126212/orig/55828.jpg"
```